# How to declare classmethod or function inside a class dynamicaly "on fly"?

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.0

I try to create a class dynamically using a fabric:

```
class TestFabric():
    @classmethod
    def CreateEntity(self, name):
        classname = name + 'Test'
        return type(classname, (models.Model,), {
            'Attr1':models.CharField(),
            'Attr2':models.CharField(),
        })
    pass
```

when I then call function

```
TestFabric.CreateEntity("Person")
```

the class PersonTest is created. I could then create instances of this class and so on.
This is equal to

```
class PersonTest(models.Model):
    Attr1: models.CharField()
    Attr2: models.CharField()
```

But what if I have to define a method inside this class?
For example:

```
class PersonTest(models.Model):
    Attr1:
    Attr2:
    def SomeMethod(self, Atrr1, Attr2):
        smth here
        return ....
```

The question is:
How can I define a method **inside** this class **dynamically**?
Note, that I have to add this method for a class, not for a concrete instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just create method and assign it to object:

```
class PersonTest(object):
    x = 4


def SomeMethod(self, value1, value2):
    return self.x + value1 + value2

PersonTest.itsugly = SomeMethod

person = PersonTest()
print(person.itsugly(3, 4))
>> 11
```

It's kinda ugly, but works fine.

Comment: This is a good option if u define a class as a static, but in my case, I try to create this class "on fly". So if I just type "Classname.Propertymethodname" = "Functionname" this will not work, as at this time class even does not exists at all. As you may see I try to define class in a fabric - function that returns me a class (not an instance of it). So I don't know the correct sintax - How can I define a class method inside a fabric?